# ConnectorID should contain 1,2,3... Find Connector ID's with missing numbers (1,2,3)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can someone please help me write a query (T-SQL) checking for the missing # from comparing the connector ID then look for the missing number within the # field?

So, for example the Connector ID 12345678 should contain 1, 2 and 3 (individual rows) and in this example, it was missing #2. I need a result that would come back with 12345678|2

```
ConnectorID|#
12345678|1
12345678|3
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is `SQL Filling gaps` case. [Similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+Filling+gaps).
See query example with recursion

```
with rCte as (
    -- anchor - first row of gap
  select ConnectorId,n+1 n,next_n
  from ( 
      select *
         ,lead(n,1,n)over(partition by ConnectorId order by n)next_n
      from test
   )t
  where next_n>(n+1)
    -- next rows, if more than 1 row
union all
  select ConnectorId,n+1,next_n
  from rCte
  where (n+1)<next_n
)
select * from r
order by ConnectorId,n
option(maxrecursion 100)
```